# How to get ImageData of an externally uploaded image?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

[image]

I want to get ImageData of above image.In return, I am not getting any data as a result.  The code which i tried to execute is attached below.

```js
function drawImage(imageObj) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var imageX = 69;
        var imageY = 50;
        var imageWidth = imageObj.width;
        var imageHeight = imageObj.height;

        context.drawImage(imageObj, imageX, imageY);

        var imageData = context.getImageData(10, 10, 50, 50);
        var data = imageData.data;

        // iterate over all pixels
        for(var i = 0, n = data.length; i < n; i += 4) {
          var red = data[i];
          var green = data[i + 1];
          var blue = data[i + 2];
          var alpha = data[i + 3];
          alert(red + " " + green + " " + blue + " " + alpha);
        }

       
       
      }
      var imageObj = new Image();
      imageObj.onload = function() {
        drawImage(this);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'Images/graph.gif'
```

```html
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="400"></canvas>
  </body>
```

Comment: What do you mean "not getting any data" ? Check if there is an error by viewing the console (hit F12 on most browsers) as it could be one of many errors associated with the image and its URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are getting no data because that part of your canvas has no drawings on it.**

You are drawing the image rightward by 69 pixels and only fetching the leftmost 60 pixels.

```
var imageX = 69;
var imageY = 50;

// drawing image starting at x=69
context.drawImage(imageObj, imageX, imageY);

...

// fetching image data from x=10 through x=60 (Nothing is drawn here!)
var imageData = context.getImageData(10, 10, 50, 50);
```

BTW, you are actually getting data, but the empty part of a canvas will always return zeros for the red, green, blue & alpha components.